# PHP- Como passar um id através de uma janela modal

Tags: php, html, modal

Não estou conseguindo passar um id pra uma janela modal. Poderia me ajudar?

Estou utilizando uma table, na qual lista todos os nomes e CNPJ's dos clientes cadastrados.

Criei um loop, para mostrar em cada linha da tabela, os botões alterar e excluir.

O botão alterar funciona perfeitamente, mas o de excluir (o que está chamando a modal para confirmar a exclusão do cliente, está levando apenas o id do primeiro cliente da tabela, e não do cliente selecionado).

Segue o código da página com a table e a modal:

include "../conexao.php";

$comando = "Select * from tbcliente";

if (!empty($pesq)) {
$comando .= " where razao_social LIKE '%" . $pesq . "%' ";
}elseif(!empty($pesq2)){
$comando .= " where cnpj = $pesq2";
}

$comando .= " order by razao_social";

$sql = mysqli_query($conecta, $comando);

?>

## **Consulta de Clientes**

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height:480px; max-height: 480px;"> 


<table style="width: 80%; background-color: #fff" align="center" border="0">

    <tr>
        <th style="width: 50%; background-color: #2e4e8e; color: #fff;">
            <form action='clienteconsulta.php' method="GET" >
                Nome<br><br>
                <input type="text" name='pesquisa' value='<?php echo $pesq ?>'style="height: 30px; color:#000;" >
        </th>
        <th style="background-color: #2e4e8e;color: #fff;">
            CNPJ<br><br>
            <input type="text" name='consultacnpj' value='<?php echo $pesq2 ?>' style="height: 30px; color:#000;">
        </th>
        <th style="background-color: #2e4e8e;color: #fff;">&nbsp;<br><br>
            <button input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
        </th>
        <th style="background-color: #2e4e8e;color: #fff;">&nbsp;</th>
            </form>
    </tr>

    <?php
    
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        ?>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><?php echo $result['RAZAO_SOCIAL']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['CNPJ'] . "&nbsp"; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a style="text-align: center;" href="clientealtera.php?id=<?php echo $result['IDCLIENTE']; ?>">
                    <span class="">Alterar</span><br>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExemploModalCentralizado">
                    Excluir
                </a>
                <div class="modal fade" id="ExemploModalCentralizado" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="TituloModalCentralizado" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title" align="left"><strong>Confirmação de exclusão</strong></h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body" align="left">
                                Deseja realmente excluir o cliente selecionado?
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                <a href="clientedelete.php?id=<?php echo $result['IDCLIENTE']; ?>"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
</div>
```

OBS: Se colocar a função href="clientedelete.php?id=" dentro do botão de excluir fora da modal, ele leva o id correto para a exclusão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo devido sua organização do código, `ids` não podem se repetir, no seu loop quando você clica para excluir o terceiro itém, por exemplo, na verdade você está chamando o primeiro modal da listagem. Devido eles terem o mesmo seletor de chamada `id="ExemploModalCentralizado"`, você pode resolver isso adicionando uma variável de auto incremento `$i++;` logo depois que você abre seu `while` e concatenar ela com id do modal, assim você cria ids únicos para cada modal.

Mas faço uma observação, como está usando bootstrap há formas de você usar apenas um modal e passar os valores que precisa de acordo com a linha clicada, da uma olha no final da documentação de modal do bootstrap, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

```
...data-target="#ExemploModalCentralizado-<?php echo $i; ?>"...
...id="ExemploModalCentralizado-<?php echo $i; ?>"...
```

O código completo ficaria assim:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height:480px; max-height: 480px;"> 


<table style="width: 80%; background-color: #fff" align="center" border="0">

    <tr>
        <th style="width: 50%; background-color: #2e4e8e; color: #fff;">
            <form action='clienteconsulta.php' method="GET" >
                Nome<br><br>
                <input type="text" name='pesquisa' value='<?php echo $pesq ?>'style="height: 30px; color:#000;" >
        </th>
        <th style="background-color: #2e4e8e;color: #fff;">
            CNPJ<br><br>
            <input type="text" name='consultacnpj' value='<?php echo $pesq2 ?>' style="height: 30px; color:#000;">
        </th>
        <th style="background-color: #2e4e8e;color: #fff;">&nbsp;<br><br>
            <button input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
        </th>
        <th style="background-color: #2e4e8e;color: #fff;">&nbsp;</th>
            </form>
    </tr>

    <?php
    
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $i++;
        ?>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><?php echo $result['RAZAO_SOCIAL']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['CNPJ'] . "&nbsp"; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a style="text-align: center;" href="clientealtera.php?id=<?php echo $result['IDCLIENTE']; ?>">
                    <span class="">Alterar</span><br>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ExemploModalCentralizado-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    Excluir
                </a>
                <div class="modal fade" id="ExemploModalCentralizado-<?php echo $i; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="TituloModalCentralizado" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title" align="left"><strong>Confirmação de exclusão</strong></h4>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body" align="left">
                                Deseja realmente excluir o cliente selecionado?
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                                <a href="clientedelete.php?id=<?php echo $result['IDCLIENTE']; ?>"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button> </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado!